# 'Location myLocation does not support this operation.' When trying to get a specific row in BigQuery using node client

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-api-nodejs-client

I have a cloud function that uses bigquery client to make operations. Ultimately I'm looking to check if a row with an specific id exists so I built the following function (for now I'm just looking to make the request work and log the results):

```
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

const bigquery = new BigQuery({
  projectId: 'myProjectID',
  keyFilename: 'mykey.json'
});

 await idExist('MyID--Ak2aRpL0','myProjectID.myDatasetID.myTableName')

  async function idExist (id,table){
    console.log('Checking if it exist')

    const query = `SELECT * FROM \`${table}\` WHERE id='${id}'`;
    const options = {
      query: query,
      location: table
    }

    const [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob(options);
    console.log(`Job '${job.id}' started.`);

    const [rows] = await job.getQueryResults();

    console.log('Resulted Rows:');
    rows.forEach(row => console.log(row));
  }
```

When I run this I get `Error: Location projectID.datasetId.tableName does not support this operation. at new ApiError (/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:75:15)`

Things I tried:

- Making sure that the service account that I'm using have "Big Query Data Editor" and "Big Query User" roles. Both should give me access to create jobs and manage tables.
- Different combinations of locations 'datasetID.tableName' and 'tableName' only. All with the same error result.
- Running the SAME query on the SQL workspace in browser (with an account with data editor + query user roles). This worked fine and was able to retrieve the row perfectly.
- Re-checked :) that the SA contains 'Data Editor' and 'User' roles
- Edit: As suggested I also tried running `SELECT 1 AS TEST` and `SELECT count(1) FROM myProjectID.myDatasetID.myTableName` with the same result.

Notes:

- The function is a firebase function, and the service account is the firebase-adminsdk, I added the big query roles to that one.
  -Inserting a row using the client works fine:

```
await bigquery.dataset('datasetID').table('tableName').insert(myObject);
```

- Querying using query() function works. So maybe an issue with creating jobs? I would prefer to use jobs for this to prevent having the function running too much time.

```
const result = await bigquery.query(query);
```

I would really appreciate some help/guidance on this issue. Let me know If I'm missing any helpful information.

Thanks!!

Comment: Could you please try to set a fixed query  `Select 1 as Test` . Then run `Select count(1) from myProjectID.myDatasetID.myTableName` .Please check that your table does not require a where condition on the partiton column.

Comment: Both SELECT 1 AS TEST and SELECT count(1) FROM TABLE returned the same error. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Since you cannot start a query, please check that your service account has the needed rights and your are in the right project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the wrong tutorial and made a simple mistake. In the query options `location` means the fisical location of the dataset not the location of the table, mine was US. So the following options fixed the issue:

```
const options = {
  query: query,
  location: 'US'
}
```